# Create a new grouping of existing categories and summarize the new groups

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that currently has one column with 8 energy types. I want to aggregate that column into  just two types like this.

1. Energy types Hydro, Geothermal, Wind, Solar, Pumped Hydro are type "Renewable Energy"
2. The other 3 types are "Non-Renewable Energy"

Having created this new set of categories I want to group by countries and then sum for each of the "year" columns in the dataframe which have names like `energyProd_2016`

Current look of the dataset is below

```r
top10ProducersMod <- 
    structure(list(country = c("DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
    "DE", "DE", "ES", "ES", "ES", "ES", "ES", "ES", "ES", "ES", "FR", 
    "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "IT", "IT", "IT", "IT", 
    "IT", "IT", "IT", "IT", "PL", "PL", "PL", "PL", "PL", "PL", "PL", 
    "PL", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "UK", "UK", 
    "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", 
    "NO", "NO", "NO", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", "TR", 
    "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA", "UA"), country_name = c("Germany", 
    "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
    "Germany", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
    "Spain", "Spain", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
    "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", 
    "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Sweden", "Sweden", 
    "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "United Kingdom", 
    "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
    "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "Norway", 
    "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", 
    "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", 
    "Turkey", "Ukraine", "Ukraine", "Ukraine", "Ukraine", "Ukraine", 
    "Ukraine", "Ukraine", "Ukraine"), type = c("Conventional thermal", 
    "Nuclear", "Hydro", "Pumped hydro power", "Wind", "Solar", "Geothermal", 
    "Other", "Conventional thermal", "Nuclear", "Hydro", "Pumped hydro power", 
    "Wind", "Solar", "Geothermal", "Other", "Conventional thermal", 
    "Nuclear", "Hydro", "Pumped hydro power", "Wind", "Solar", "Geothermal", 
    "Other", "Conventional thermal", "Nuclear", "Hydro", "Pumped hydro power", 
    "Wind", "Solar", "Geothermal", "Other", "Conventional thermal", 
    "Nuclear", "Hydro", "Pumped hydro power", "Wind", "Solar", "Geothermal", 
    "Other", "Conventional thermal", "Nuclear", "Hydro", "Pumped hydro power", 
    "Wind", "Solar", "Geothermal", "Other", "Conventional thermal", 
    "Nuclear", "Hydro", "Pumped hydro power", "Wind", "Solar", "Geothermal", 
    "Other", "Conventional thermal", "Nuclear", "Hydro", "Pumped hydro power", 
    "Wind", "Solar", "Geothermal", "Other", "Conventional thermal", 
    "Nuclear", "Hydro", "Pumped hydro power", "Wind", "Solar", "Geothermal", 
    "Other", "Conventional thermal", "Nuclear", "Hydro", "Pumped hydro power", 
    "Wind", "Solar", "Geothermal", "Other"), energyProd_2016 = c(390141, 
    80038, 25690, 5451, 78218, 38098, 165, 1805, 108210, 56100, 39180, 
    3410, 47712, 13051, 0, 91, 60607.854, 384008.125, 64879.956, 
    4786.979, 21472.916, 8657.27, 87.933, 559.515, 190121, 0, 43784.622, 
    1825.204, 17523, 21757, 5867, 650, 136945, 0, 2591, 474, 12279, 
    124, 0, 64, 14621, 60524, 61764, 119, 15479, 143, 0, 0, 203165.188, 
    65149.08, 8286.51, 2948.89, 37262.699, 10410.948, 0, 0, 3212, 
    0, 143442, 999, 2116, 0, 0, 297, 174166, 0, 66686, 0, 15381, 
    1013, 4010, 681, 65415, 75931, 9025, 1633, 949, 490, 0, 79), 
        energyProd_2017 = c(376128, 72155, 25888, 5910, 103707, 39401, 
        157, 1623, 126885, 55540, 20708, 2249, 47929, 13778, 0, 78, 
        68922.949, 379093.955, 54432.864, 5070.791, 24710.749, 9572.843, 
        119.937, 673.71, 199722.444, 0, 37556.721, 1825.96, 17565.332, 
        24016.821, 5821.46, 582.871, 137068.099, 0, 2999.86, 448.193, 
        14574.192, 165.463, 0, 61.73, 15003, 63008, 64676, 25, 17609, 
        230, 0, 0, 189296.528, 63886.86, 8723.43, 2862.01, 50003.654, 
        11524.87, 0, 0, 3233, 0, 142276, 1157, 2852, 0, 0, 281, 199910.043, 
        0, 57823.851, 0, 17793.167, 2817.837, 5101.487, 811.134, 
        54041.9, 80295.3, 8812, 1559, 974, 737.6, 0, 45), energyProd_2018 = c(320437.701, 
        72274.133, 20041.878, 6661.083, 112174, 46184, 165.25, 522.751, 
        110084.238, 53270.8, 36083.636, 2009.408, 49495.207, 12137.315, 
        0, 0, 53956.44, 393153.254, 68706.552, 9082.043, 26134.02, 
        9651.478, 84.084, 0, 185046, 0, 49275, 1632, 17318, 22887, 
        5708, 0, 138957.387, 0, 2353.336, 402.36, 12487.345, 298.432, 
        0, 0, 14869.986, 65801.155, 60977.602, 0, 16638.345, 0, 0, 
        0, 180837.905, 59097.753, 7678.659, 2515.998, 56903.961, 
        12857.349, 0, 0, 3457.28, 0, 139512.026, 3490.918, 3875.881, 
        0, 0, 0, 195153.546, 0, 59865.351, 0, 19825.697, 7459.485, 
        6275.373, 703.126, 60830.7, 84397.9, 11920.2, 0, 1185.9, 
        737.8, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want it to be like this

```
DE Germany Renewable Energy      amount1  amount2 amount3
DE Germany Non-Renewable Energy  amount4  amount5 amount6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be:

```
library(tidyverse)
top10ProducersMod %>% 
  mutate(type2 = if_else(type %in% c('Hydro', 'Geothermal', 'Wind', 'Solar', 'Pumped hydro power'), 'Renewable_Energy', 'Non-Renewable_Energy')) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(country:type, type2), names_to = 'energy_year', values_to = 'prod') %>%
  group_by(country, country_name, type2, energy_year) %>%
  summarise(prod = sum(prod)) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = prod, names_from = energy_year)

# country country_name type2      energyProd_2016 energyProd_2017 energyProd_2018
# <chr>   <chr>        <chr>                <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1 DE      Germany      Non-Renew~         471984          449906          393235.
# 2 DE      Germany      Renewable~         147622          175063          185226.
# 3 ES      Spain        Non-Renew~         164401          182503          163355.
# 4 ES      Spain        Renewable~         103353           84664           99726.
# 5 FR      France       Non-Renew~         445175.         448691.         447110.
# 6 FR      France       Renewable~          99885.          93907.         113658.
```

Answer (score 3):

Using *data.table*, create grouping column for *Energy* type, then group by sum multiple columns:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(top10ProducersMod)

# make a grouping column
top10ProducersMod[, Energy := ifelse(type %in% c("Hydro", "Geothermal", "Wind", "Solar", "Pumped hydro power"), 
                                     "Renewable Energy", "Non-Renewable Energy") ]

# then group by columns, and sum on selected columns
top10ProducersMod[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(country, country_name, Energy), .SDcols = 4:6 ]
#     country   country_name               Energy energyProd_2016 energyProd_2017 energyProd_2018
# 1:      DE        Germany Non-Renewable Energy       471984.00       449906.00       393234.59
# 2:      DE        Germany     Renewable Energy       147622.00       175063.00       185226.21
# 3:      ES          Spain Non-Renewable Energy       164401.00       182503.00       163355.04
# 4:      ES          Spain     Renewable Energy       103353.00        84664.00        99725.57
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Also `dplyr` but without the pivotting...

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   mutate(renewable = case_when(
      type == "Hydro" ~ "Renewable Energy",
      type == "Geothermal" ~ "Renewable Energy",
      type == "Wind" ~ "Renewable Energy",
      type == "Solar" ~ "Renewable Energy",
      type == "Pumped hydro power" ~ "Renewable Energy",
      TRUE ~ "Non-Renewable Energy")
      ) %>%
   group_by(country, country_name, renewable) %>%
   summarise(across(starts_with("energyProd_"), sum, .names = "{.col}"))

#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'country', 'country_name' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 6
#> # Groups:   country, country_name [10]
#>    country country_name renewable energyProd_2016 energyProd_2017
#>    <chr>   <chr>        <chr>               <dbl>           <dbl>
#>  1 DE      Germany      Non-Rene…         471984          449906 
#>  2 DE      Germany      Renewabl…         147622          175063 
#>  3 ES      Spain        Non-Rene…         164401          182503 
#>  4 ES      Spain        Renewabl…         103353           84664 
#>  5 FR      France       Non-Rene…         445175.         448691.
#>  6 FR      France       Renewabl…          99885.          93907.
#>  7 IT      Italy        Non-Rene…         190771          200305.
#>  8 IT      Italy        Renewabl…          90757.          86786.
#>  9 NO      Norway       Non-Rene…           3509            3514 
#> 10 NO      Norway       Renewabl…         146557          146285 
#> 11 PL      Poland       Non-Rene…         137009          137130.
#> 12 PL      Poland       Renewabl…          15468           18188.
#> 13 SE      Sweden       Non-Rene…          75145           78011 
#> 14 SE      Sweden       Renewabl…          77505           82540 
#> 15 TR      Turkey       Non-Rene…         174847          200721.
#> 16 TR      Turkey       Renewabl…          87090           83536.
#> 17 UA      Ukraine      Non-Rene…         141425          134382.
#> 18 UA      Ukraine      Renewabl…          12097           12083.
#> 19 UK      United King… Non-Rene…         268314.         253183.
#> 20 UK      United King… Renewabl…          58909.          73114.
#> # … with 1 more variable: energyProd_2018 <dbl>
```

Comment: `if_else(... %in% ...)` would be so much less typing here.

Comment: True, just a trade-off between typing and a perception of clarity.